# Ordenar valores en grafica de barra horizontal

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

como se encuentran. Debía sacar los 5 departamentos con mayor número de desmovilizados, lo cual logre filtrar y sacar bien, creo. Al momento de graficar no me aparecía ordenado los valores como en el ejemplo que me otorgaron.

Ejemplo de como debe quedar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código que tengo hasta ahora es:

```
filtro_des = df['TipoDeDesmovilizacion']=='Individual'

filtro_final = df[filtro_des]
filtro_final = filtro_final['DepartamentoDeResidencia'].value_counts()
top = filtro_final.head(5)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

top.(inplace=True)
grafica = dict(sorted(top.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))

y = list(grafica.values())
x = list(grafica.keys())
ax.barh(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Lo que me arroja el código es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deberia aparecer de mayor a menor, pero aun no se he entendido como lo puedo ordeno.

Comment: Y si pones `x[1]` en la función lambda?

Comment: Gracias, si me funciono. MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: De nada. Estabas ordenando de acuerdo al nombre y no al valor

Comment: Tengo una pregunta aparte, muchas gracias de ante mano porque comprendí el error. Como puedo convertir un dataframe en una matriz ?

Comment: `pandas` utiliza `numpy` y al igual que puedes convertirlo a un diccionario con `.to_dict()` lo puedes convertir a numpy_array con `df.to_numpy()`

Comment: Puedo seleccionar dos columnas de un df y eso convertirlo en matriz con `df.to_numpy()`?

Comment: Claro que sí. Un dataframe se compone de series y siempre que tengas más de 1 columna tendrás un dataframe

Comment: Gracias, pero creo que entendí tu explicación mas no lo que tengo que hacer sobre lo que me pidieron. Puedo hacerte mas preguntas ?  es que estoy muy confundido sobre lo que me piden.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132003/discussion-between-christian-and-john-james).